# can i work on mono under Windows xp?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, windows-xp

How can I install and work with mono on windows xp sp3?

*Now I am using mono with the Ubuntu OS on my system.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install Mono on Windows. You just need to make sure you run Mono when you want .NET and the other way around. If you don't use Mono-specific stuff it's possible to use MS.NET instead.

[Read more about installing Mono on Windows here.](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aWindows)

Comment: is mono supported by microsoft ?

Comment: No, Mono is not supported by Microsoft. The .NET framework is the official, Microsoft-endorsed product - no surprise there.

Comment: @vishnu: Not really. Mono is open-source backed by Novell (a Linux distro company)

Comment: ok. So Novell linux distro will have the mono installed by default.

Comment: @vishnu: I don't know really, never used their Linux distributions  but it does indeed sound likely :)